# Assigning Image Views to Background image Of Button

Tags: iphone

I am trying to combine two image views and put them into another image view which I am assigning to background image of a button.Somehow this is not working.Could someone please check and let me know what exactly is wrong here.

```
    UIImageView * image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"homesmall.png"]];
    UIImageView * image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"update.png"]];

    [image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(16,0,16,16)];
    [image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,16,16)];

    UIImageView *cellAcc = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,16)];

    [cellAcc addSubview:image1];
    [cellAcc addSubview:image2];
    UIImage *image = [cellAcc image];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding them as subviews. There is no additive property here. You will have to use quartz to draw them into an image context and extract the combined image.

**Edit**

You can replace

```
UIImage *image = [cellAcc image];
```

with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cellAcc.bounds.size);
[cellAcc.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I tried this and this also  works


        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(32, 16);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
  CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(16, 0.0, 16, 16);
  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"homesmall.png"] drawInRect:imageRect];
  CGRect imageRect1 = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 16, 16);
  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"update.png"] drawInRect:imageRect1];
   
  UIImage *image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();